# Add (open/close) button to activity for (opening/closing) the navigation drawer

Tags: android, button, android-activity, drawer

I am currently learning about the Navigation Drawer from the android site, and I am using their example http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

What I want is to add a button in the `MainActivity` which would be able to open the `NavigationDrawer`. I need to do it programmatically, not in XML. How can I do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Create a method in `MainActivity` which contains your drawerLayout.

```
public void open()
{
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

and from Your fragment
In oncreateView() method As you want new Button Programmatically add Button in Your Root inflated layout. Your fragment has button 
bellow I modified fragment try

```
 public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        RelativeLayout root=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.root);
        Button button=new Button(getActivity());            
        LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        button.setText("openDrawer");
        root.addView(button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).open();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    }
 }
```

You can try this code in your fragment..

Comment: but how do I add the button?

Comment: In answer I have not added button in activity but in fragment,So you can access Drawer from any fragment and from any views click event by calling activity open() method.

Comment: Why Gravity.LEFT?  Why not RIGHT or something else?  Is that really relevant or do you just need an int?  Not questioning you -- hoping for better understanding.

Comment: usually navigation drawer open from the left side(as by clicking the icon left to the app logo). See the standered Google apps. But it is also possible to open Nav. drawer from right too..(depends upon needs)

Comment: HI want to open drawer from any activity of app.

Comment: @PriyankaChauhan I 'll suggest you to look into [same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities) and  [android-navigationdrawer-multiple-activities-same-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095691/android-navigationdrawer-multiple-activities-same-menu) and [navigation-drawer-to-switch-activities-instead-of-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442378/navigation-drawer-to-switch-activities-instead-of-fragments)

Answer (score 13):

Create your Button in `onCreate(Bundle)` method:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
```

Find your `DrawerLayout`:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_drawer_layout_id);
```

Set an `OnClickListener` on this button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);   
    }
)
```

This will give you an empty drawer. If you have a `View` that you would like to place inside the drawer, replace:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

with:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(myCustomView);
```

If you want the button to toggle the drawer(close the drawer if its open or, open it if its closed) use the following `OnClickListener`:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); 
        }  
    }
)
```

If you are using a custom view, use this `OnClickListener`:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(myCustomView)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(myCustomView);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(myCustomView); 
        }  
    }
)
```

Comment: the button is still nowhere to be seen

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer Can you post your layout xml file? The one that your use in `setContentView()`?