# android: Launch the navigation bar dropdown menu with a button

Tags: android, android-button, android-menu, android-navigation

I'm trying to write code so that when a button is pressed, the dropdown menu in the navigation bar comes up. I tried making something similar to the following prefab function (which I understand to be the one responsible for opening the menu)

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_class, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Problem is that I don't know where they get the `menu` variable from. What should I put in it's place to complete the following function?

```
public void launchMenu(View view) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_class, (Menu) /* menu variable */);
}
```

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu()` *creates* and populates the menu, but it doesn't display it.

Answer (score 0):

Create this method in `MainActivity` which contains your navigation drawerLayout.

```
public void open()
{
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

[Check this SO question for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853094/add-button-to-activity-with-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this...

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```