# How to reuse navigation bar code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a class named MainActivity.java, this java contains Navigation Bar code.

If I want to build another activity named Contact.java and there also contains Navigation Bar code.  How do I reuse Navigation Bar code from MainActivity.java to Contact.java? Can I create a class to solve it?

Here is my code:

```html
package com.thisistap.isuper.www.contactbook;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import com.thisistap.isuper.www.contactbook.nav.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private Button contact_button;
    private TabHost mTabHost = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // defined elements from layout (it can be modified)
        contact_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button);

        // --- [Start] defined elements from Navigation Bar (it cannot be modified from here) ---
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // --- [End] defined elements from Navigation Bar (it cannot be modified from here) ---

        // --- [Start] Button Group ---
        contact_button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Contact.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        // --- [End] Button Group ---
    }

    // --- [Start] Navigation Bar Action (it cannot be modified from here) ---
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Contact.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    // --- [End] Navigation Bar Action (it cannot be modified from here) ---
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you extendig your activities from a base activity and implement your common logic into this parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this - Take all your drawer code in a BaseActivity and in XML of BaseActivity put DrawerLayout as parent along with a container(like you do it for fragments) and NavigationView. You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36103112/3260244) answer. It addresses the same issue.

Then extend BaseActivity to your MainActivity and instead of using setContentView(), inflate it in the container of your BaseActivity.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // --- [Start] defined elements from Navigation Bar (it cannot be modified from here) ---
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    // --- [End] defined elements from Navigation Bar (it cannot be modified from here) ---

}

// --- [Start] Navigation Bar Action (it cannot be modified from here) ---
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Contact.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
// --- [End] Navigation Bar Action (it cannot be modified from here) ---
}
```

Then extend in your MainActivity -

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   FrameLayout containerParent = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
   getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, containerParent);

 contact_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_button);
}
    }
```

Your BaseActivity XML should be like this -

```
<DrawerLayout --->
    <FrameLayout ---/>
    <NavigationView-------/>
</DrawerLayout/>
```