# Implement Same Navigation View along different Activites in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, navigationview, android-navigationview

Perhaps somebody can help me understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19451842/5482999) question about the subject.
I already made my navigation view, but now I want the same navigation view in my other 2 activities.
What I don't understand is how should I properly implement my layouts for the rest of the activities, because trying I ended up practically cloning the first layout.
My doubt is exclusively on the building/writing of the layouts for the other activities.
Would have comented there, but my reputation does not allow me.

Comment: you can use fragments for that pupose

Comment: I want to use activities, because in the second activity I have a SectionsPagerAdapter

Comment: Link which u have metioned in the question has already answer..You have to use understand the code

Comment: Yep, I know they I have an answer already, but I don't clearly understand it, since I can't comment over there, I posted looking for some light. @Abhishek Tyagi already gave me some. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fragments, make your navigation layout a fragment and place that fragment wherever you need that layout or you can also create a parent activity class in which you implement your navigation layout and extend that activity in rest of your activities.

Comment: I did extended my second activity to my Main activity with the Navigation Drawer, but I ended up almost cloning my Main activity for my second activity.
Don't want to use fragments because my Main activity is made of 4 fragments and I don't have much experience with fragments.

Comment: don't extend your main activity, create a base activity class and extend it in both the activities. The base activity can contain all of the common code

Comment: Thank you, now you give me some light, I thought when they mentioned BaseActivity, was extending an activity with a NavigationView already implemented not a "BaseActivity" itself. Thank You @Abhishek Tyagi, I'll see what I can do now, with your useful clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36103112/5482999) is the EASIEST and CLEARER implementation for what I wanted to achieve, code might use some optimization, but does what I was looking for after reading several posts in the last three days.